# How to enable clickable links in Visual Studio terminal?

Tags: visual-studio, powershell, visual-studio-2022

One of the cool things about using PowerShell in the Terminal app is the ability to Ctrl+Click on a link:

[image]

I am using the same PowerShell in the Visual Studio's built-in Terminal, but links don't show up. Is there a way to turn them on?  I don't see anything obvious.

[image]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There doesn't appear to be an option to do this.  The Terminal application appears to be able to detect and make URLs clickable as noted in the settings, so its not something specific to Powershell or Visual Studio:

[image: terminal setting]

Since Visual Studio is simply using the shell, the same behavior is exhibited as if you were using Powershell standalone.